# Does EF Core support TransactionScope?

Tags: entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-3.1, transactionscope

I have **.NET Core 3.1** and **EntityFrameworkCore 3.1.8**.

In a command (which writes data to db) I use `SaveChanges()` method multiple times. Therefore, I decided to make all these transactional and use `TransactionScope()` like this:

```
using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
{
}
```

Is this a correct approach? Will this work correctly?

**Note: I have one DbContext**

Comment: It should be nested transactions? I prefer do not use TransactionScope at all it is more related to distributed transactions.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, `TransactionScope` would most likely work for you. As a personal recommendation, I would use `DbContext.Database.BeginTransaction()` instead.

The reason for this is because `TransactionScope` must be implemented by the library you are using. In general, SDKs for relational databases should support `TransactionScope` (I know Microsoft.Data.SqlClient for SQL Server does, not sure about the other databases).

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/transactions#using-systemtransactions

Comment: Not an answer at all - the question is quite explicit about what it asks, which is totally ignored. Also TransactionScope for ages has special optimization (for only one source).

Comment: Correct. I will amend my answer accordingly.